# load configuration file into dictionary using one liner in python

Tags: python

I am trying to load a configuration file into a dictionary with just one liner

The configuration file looks like this:

```
key1:
   nested-key1 = val1
   nested-key2 = val2

key2:
   nested-key3 = val3
```

The dictionary I'm trying to build should look like this:

```
 { key1:{nested-key1:val1, nested-key2:val2}, key2:{nested-key3:val3}}
```

By one liner I mean that I don't want to use a loop - just a fixed sequence of function calls (Number of key may vary).

something like:

```
f = open("/tmp/config")
dic = f.read().split("\n\n") ...
```

Comment: And what's the rational behind "I don't want to use a loop" ? you understand that it means that you'll have to manually repeat the same command as many times as there are keys in the file? Do you know in advance the exact number of keys ?

Comment: no. the number of keys is unknown. (question edited)

Comment: so you can't do it without looping.

Comment: @alfasin you can always replace a loop with recursive function calls

Comment: @Alik right, you can also cross the highway with a bucket on your head. The fact that you *can* do something doesn't mean that you *should* do it. (Especially when the OP don't provide a good reasoning for a silly restriction).

Comment: It's not for production, I'm just playing and I felt that this is doable but I haven't succeeded to solve it myself.

Comment: You realize of course that some kind of iteration/looping would still be required even if you don't explicitly use ``for`` or ``while``? As said in earlier comments you could do this recursively as this is a "parsing" problem. If I had more time I could replace all looping constructs one might use for a map/reduce style functional approach -- but you're just "hiding" the looping/iteration in something else.

Comment: why don't use `json files`?
with `json` package its very comfortable.

Comment: Hiding the iteration could also be nice. I was hoping to do it with some text replacement and 'eval' but maybe I'm far off

Comment: I don't think a single regular expression or search/replace could handle this in a generic way.

Comment: @Zaaferani how would you do it with a json lib?

Comment: @Ezra see:
https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2835559/parsing-values-from-a-json-file-in-python

Comment: This is what I've come up with having a play with [funcy](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/funcy) -- https://gist.github.com/prologic/9b31c053d1be2ebab8bd -- I'm sure some of this can be even further simplified and cleaned up; but it works (tm) :)

Comment: Of course -- The syntax of this configuration file here is remarkably similar to YAML :)

Answer (score 3):

Considering the similarity of the file format to the YAML format, I suggest you use a YAML parser:

```
import yaml

s = """
key1:
   nested-key1 = val1
   nested-key2 = val2

key2:
   nested-key3 = val3
"""

print yaml.load(s.replace("=", ":"))
```

The output is:

```
{'key2': 'nested-key3 , val3', 'key1': 'nested-key1 , val1 nested-key2 , val2'}
```

For reference:

- https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.replace
- https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PyYAML

Comment: Great answer! Even if it doesn't directly answer the OP's question of a one-liner avoiding loops/iteration weird ways :)